# Linux Sever form Update Error

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter, I have used CKeditors they are working fine on local Windows Machine but as my website is on linux server. So when I try to insert a table in my editor any click save it simply crashes. Although same editor and code is working fine with simple data on linux. Any Idea to solve this ?

Comment: Check the error logs.

Comment: Yes I have tried that but there were no error related to this, although I have removed all of them but still I have this issue

Comment: Can you provide a link to the "FC editors" you refer? What do you mean by "simply crashes"?

Comment: The page must redirect on to listing of products page after update but it not working in this case it shows empty page and don't update the record

Comment: That the symptom of a 500 internal server error, which indicates a PHP fatal error. Check if you have all logs well configured and look for errors in apache logs, php logs and syslog to make sure you find out what is going wrong.

Comment: http://ckeditor.com/download this editor

Comment: So the error was in my query, that table when I insert from editor puts "100%" width and this "%" breaks my query this was like SQL Injection. Linux don't bear such errors and windows isn't much efficient to dig out such errors. Now I'm finding a solution for this. BTW thanks for help cheers

Comment: You should update your question with the error description and proper tags so that people could try to help you solve your new found problem.